# No Wi-Fi after sleep

Tags: wifi, networking

my Wi-fi won't work after sleep. My card is Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3).

`/var/log/syslog` says :

```
Mar  8 00:31:15 Laptop kernel: [ 1396.243632] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
```

How to make it work ? :(

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

That card has some issues with iwlwifi driver in sleep mode.

You can turn off the power management with this command from terminal:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

When you reboot your system you will lost this change,  so if you want to make it pemanently, you must modify your driver configuration with the following commands:

```
echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
```

I recommend using the first option before making any final changes with the second option.